# ASP.NET Web Site template equivalent in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

Apparently Microsoft has changed the templates around since 2010 and now there is no generic "web site" template in Visual Studio 2013 when attempting to create a ASP.NET web site. The tutorials I'm following to learn the framework all have an "ASP.NET Web Site" template option while I have this but with "razor syntax". Is there a way I can get this exact template without the new razor syntax?

Comment: In general, you can't exactly use a tutorial that was written for one version of Visual Studio with another.  You will have to do some adaptation, as things change from version to version.  If they stayed the same, there would be no point in a new version.

Answer (score 2):

When you create the web aplication Select the Web Forms option.  Here is a link to a tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/creating-a-basic-web-forms-page